# Error Installing ROS on Debian Stretch

Tags: ros, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS on Debian Stretch running on a Beaglebone Black using the instructions here
http://wiki.ros.org/Debian/Installation/Source
the script file `install_ros.sh` gives the following error while executing

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

==> cmake /home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
Unhandled exception of type 'OSError':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 965, in build_workspace_isolated
    number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 665, in build_package
    destdir=destdir, use_ninja=use_ninja
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 397, in build_catkin_package
    run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, quiet, add_env=add_env)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 187, in run_command_colorized
    run_command(cmd, cwd, quiet=quiet, colorize=True, add_env=add_env)
  File "./src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 205, in run_command
    raise OSError("Failed command '%s': %s" % (cmd, e))
OSError: Failed command '['cmake', '/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Failed command '['cmake', '/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Command failed, exiting.
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Simon

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222492/error-installing-ros-on-debian-stretch/) by [simat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25326/simat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a bit of detective work I have worked out what the problem is. 'cmake' is not part of the standard Debian installation on the Beaglebone Black. Installing cmake with 'sudo apt-get install cmake' fixed this problem.

If I can edit the ROS wiki I will add the command to the script file.

My beaglebone is currently compiling ROS, has been coming up with some warnings which require the package 'python-nose'. Are these warnings important?

Simon

---

Originally posted by [simat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25326/simat/) with karma: 16 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-15**:\

> If I can edit the ROS wiki I will add the command to the script file.

Well you can, it's a wiki. Just register for an account, and you should be able to edit anything.

**Comment by [simat](https://answers.ros.org/users/25326/simat/) on 2015-12-15**:
Edited wiki, added 'sudo apt-get install cmake python-nose' to install script